# Opencart CMS - Error: Could not load model catalog/profile

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, opencart

I have a buggy problem that I'm really hoping someone can help solve if possible.

The problem exists on a website built with the CMS Opencart and started to exist after the installation of the following extension (http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=15373&filter_search=ajax%20enable%20disable%20product). Because this is not a VQmod it seems as though to fix the issue it's not possible to simply delete the extension. I have tried to look up the developer of the extension too but there is no contact information that I can see :(

The problem is in the admin panel of Opencart. When I login and browse to **catalog>products** and display a list of products then try to **'edit'** any of the products using the link, I get nothing but a blank page. I have looked around the web to see any solutions to the problem and even though there are some that describe a similar problem, none come close to a solution that I seem to be able to implement successfully.

The error log on Opencart gives me this line:

PHP Notice:  Error: Could not load model catalog/profile! in /home/sites/[**I'VE REMOVED URL**.co.uk/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 51

I have gone to that file in FTP to see if I can understand what the problem is but it makes no real sense to me, it reads:

```
global $vqmod; $file = $vqmod->modCheck($file);
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include_once($file);

        $this->registry->set('model_' . str_replace('/', '_', $model), new $class($this->registry));
    } else {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not load model ' . $model . '!');
        exit();                 
    }
```

where I think line 51 is the line

```
"trigger_error('Error: Could not load model ' . $model . '!');"
```

but I'm not 100% sure.

As you can see, I'm finding it a little difficult to even interpret what the problem is never mind actually find a solution to so any help on the issue at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If You are sure the extension You have installed is causing the problem for 100% then try to *uninstall* it by reverting the changes You have done to install it. I.e. if there is in the install manual *Find line [ABC] add after [XYZ]* then what You need to do to uninstall is *Find line [XYZ] and delete it*. If You are certain this is the only extension You have installed and incorporated into the source file itself then simply replacing the the incriminated files from the same OC version installation is the best way. Check whether the problem disappears and let us know.

Comment: Hi shadyyx, thank you very much for your response. I went to sleep last night- woke up this morning and started dropping in the .TPL files again and all of a sudden...no issue! I have a little inkling I may have been dropping the wrong files onto the server last night! Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Yes, sleeping solves so many problems...